# Background-image: cover, flickering images

Tags: css, background-image, cover

I make use of many covered background-images.

If i use the same image within the page content area and inside the fixed left panel it flickers very heavy.

Reproduced:
http://jsfiddle.net/7aUnL/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="inner">
<div class="header cover">
<div style="background-image:url(http://abload.de/img/1444863452uaupx.jpg)" class="image cover"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="flickermaker">
<div style="background-image:url(http://abload.de/img/1444863452uaupx.jpg)" class="icon cover"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

div.inner{
    margin-bottom: 120px;
    margin-left: 252px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    position: relative;
}

div.header {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

div.image {
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: -3px 0 5px 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 140px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.cover {
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

div.flickermaker{
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(205, 205, 205);
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
    position: fixed !important;
}
.icon {
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(114, 184, 251, 0.4);
    height: 100%;
    left: -3px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: border-color 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Without the small icon the problem disappears. Any suggestions?

Edit: with a smaller version of the same image everything is fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/nxU3s/1/

Comment: I don’t see any flickering …

Comment: Firefox 26 on Ubuntu. It flickers for me.

Answer (score 1):

The "flickering" image is a 1.6MB 1920x1080 file, most likely some browsers are not yet ready to deal with this range of dimensions (Firefox flickers, Chrome does not). `Background-size` is a pretty new property so don't expect perfect support in such extreme cases.

Anyway I can't see a serious real life application of your example. Use thumbnails instead of high definition images. You also need to clean your markup which is quite a nonsense.

In the end consider the `<img>` tag who will be most of the time easier to use .